# Invoking a deprecated/overloaded function using reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class called `Contract.class` which contains the following overloaded functions(among many):

```
@Deprecated
public static RemoteCall<Contract> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
    return deployRemoteCall(Contract.class, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
}
```

This java class is compiled during the execution of my program so I am using the `URLClassLoader` to load this class.

```
Class<?> cls = urlcl.loadClass("<package_name>.Contract");
```

And then I try to invoke the deploy function like this:

```
Method deployMethod = cls
                .getMethod("deploy", Web3j.class, Credentials.class, BigInteger.class, BigInteger.class);

RemoteCall<?> deployCall = (RemoteCall<?>) deployMethod
                .invoke(cls, web3j, credentials, BigInteger.valueOf(22000000000L), BigInteger.valueOf(4300000L));

Contract contract = (Contract) deployCall.send();
```

However, the code throws this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <package_name>.Contract.deploy(org.web3j.protocol.Web3j, org.web3j.crypto.Credentials, java.math.BigInteger, java.math.BigInteger
```

Although when I try to list the functions of the class with the type of its arguments, I do get this following entry:

```
deploy
arg0 org.web3j.protocol.Web3j
arg1 org.web3j.crypto.Credentials
arg2 java.math.BigInteger
arg3 java.math.BigInteger
```

Also I tried putting another function in the `Contract` class, `randomFunction` with `System.out.println("random text");` and when I invoke this `randomFunction` I do get the intended output.

So what am I missing here? Can this issue be to the fact that I am accessing an overloaded or deprecated function?

**EDIT**

I tried removing the other overloaded functions and the deprecated annotation on top of this function and I still get the same error. So it is not a problem due to either of them.

Comment: re "can this issue..."  - seems easy enough to resolve by experiment. Remove the @Deprecated annotation and try it.

Comment: @user13463803 even after removing the other overloaded functions and the deprecated tag, I get the same error. question also updated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a classloader double load conflict.

But, before we check that, make sure the static method you want to invoke is in the exact class you're reflectively loading in; static methods don't really 'do' overriding/hierarchy.

### What's a classloader double load conflict?

Let's say you have 2 custom classloaders; both having the system's app classloader (the one that loads the classes that contain your main method) as parent, and both being URLClassLoader. We shall call them 'Ali' and 'Robin'.

When you ask Ali to load class "com.foo.MyClass", Ali will first ask its parent to load it. Only if parent cannot load it will Ali then attempt to find this resource itself (by looking through its URLs for `file /com/foo/MyClass.class`), and load it as a class. Let's say that happens (Ali finds it itself). This also means that the com.foo.MyClass loaded by Ali has as its classloader 'Ali'. That means any classes that are needed to be loaded by MyClass (for example, because one of its methods has a parameter of type `org.web3j.protocol.Web3j`, that means the Web3j class also needs to be loaded) - are loaded by Ali.

You then ask Robin to load the same class. Robin too will ask parent, and now the tricky thing happens: Parent doesn't know how to load it, so Robin will... also load it.

Now we have `com.foo.MyClass` loaded two times in the system. The weird thing is, **these are completely different classes** to the VM. This gets you bizarre errors; trying to assign an instance of Ali's MyClass to a variable of type Robin's MyClass will then produce the marvelous error message 'an instance of MyClass cannot be assigned to MyClass'.

So, in other words, you're loading a version of `Contract.class` with Ali, your class has loaded the Web3j class, and you get the instance of this with `Web3j.class`, but that's Robin's Web3j. This isn't the same as Ali's Web3j even though they have the same name.

Note that if both Ali and Robin end up being asked to load a class that they both fetch via parent, this problem does not occur (as it would then be Parent's class in both cases). This is why you can just pass, say, instances of `java.lang.String` around between classes loaded by different loaders without any issue.

### How do you fix this?

One way out is to use `getMethods` and find the method you want to invoke here. Another, probably superior solution is to be careful and load *ALL* the classes with the same loader. So, don't write `Web3j.class`; write `urlcl.loadClass("org.web3j.protocol.Web3j");`. A third option is to ensure that the loader that loaded `Contract.class` is set up so that its parent will end up finding `Web3j`, and that your Web3j is loaded by that same parent (this should happen automatically is Web3j is simply on your classpath as you start the app; if the code that does the reflection has itself been loaded via a custom classloader, this gets trickier). Whether this is feasible depends on how your application has been set up.

Comment: thank you so much. you pointed in just the right direction and got so much to learn while solving this error. thanks a lot